# There is exception when install apk in android 10 by intent (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdk-tools

I'm testing my android application to support android version 10.

When I test application in android 10 device, 
there is some problem with the apk install process.

Here is my **source code** and **test information**:-

```
        File realFilePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/app-debug.apk");
        if(realFilePath.exists()) {

            Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(realFilePath);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

**error message**

```
2020-02-20 14:02:13.987 9572-9572/com.example.myapplication W/System.err: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/app-debug.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000000 }
2020-02-20 14:02:13.987 9572-9572/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2058)
2020-02-20 14:02:13.987 9572-9572/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1716)
2020-02-20 14:02:13.987 9572-9572/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5192)
2020-02-20 14:02:13.987 9572-9572/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5150)
2020-02-20 14:02:13.987 9572-9572/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5521)
2020-02-20 14:02:13.987 9572-9572/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5489)
```

**TEST information**

```
================================
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
================================
```

Android 9: there is no exception.
Android 10: there is ActivityNotFoundException and fail to install apk.

I already know that I need to use a file provider to access an external file.
But, as you can see that I set the targetSdkVersion version to 22.

> targetSdkVersion 22

Why does the error only occur on an Android 10 device?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

If there are no apps on the device that can receive the implicit intent, your app will crash when it calls **startActivity()**. To first verify that an app exists to receive the intent, call `resolveActivity()` on your Intent object. If the result is non-null, there is at least one app that can handle the intent and it's safe to call startActivity(). If the result is null, you should not use the intent.

Comment: Thank you. I checked and there was no app that handles my intent on Android 10.